# Amount to Words jar file working in ireport designer 5.6.0 but when integrated into a project its not working

Tags: java, jsp, jasper-reports

Actually i want to convert some calculation(eg:123 in Words as One Hundred Twenty Three). So i separately designed a jar file and in ireport designer 5.6.0 from "Tools"-->"options"-->"classpath" and added that jar and in "scriptlet" i wrote com.reporter.jasper.ConvertToWord and created a text field in report and added "$REPORT_SCRIPTLET.readNumber($V{Total})" and saved it. So When i click on preview tab its working perfect(eg:64501 as sixty four thousand five hundred one).

Now here comes the problem.I copied the report.jrxml and report.jasper and pasted it in "/WEB-INF/reports/report.jrxml" and run it on server  so as to convert into PDF,DOC,XLS,XLSX it is displaying an error like this image[image]

I am giving the code of jar file as well

```
package com.reporter.jasper;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDefaultScriptlet;

public class ConvertToWord extends JRDefaultScriptlet {
     String numberInWord = "";
        String inpstr = "";
        int inputLength;
        String temp = "";

        public String readNumber(double xDouble) {
            long x = (long)xDouble;
            this.inpstr = "" + x;
            this.inpstr = this.inpstr.trim();
            this.inputLength = this.inpstr.length();
            this.numberInWord = "";
            if (this.inpstr.substring(0, 1).trim().equalsIgnoreCase("-")) {
                this.inpstr = this.inpstr.substring(1);
                --this.inputLength;
            }
            this.getDigits(this.inputLength);
            return this.numberInWord;
        }
```

Showing ireport images

[image]

[image]

As you can see in above image in scriptlet class "com.reporter.jasper" is package and "ConvertToWord" is class.

In the Text field `$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.readNumber($V{Sub Total} +$V{Output VAT and CST and Service Tax})`
readNumber is method name.

So what i have to do now so that it will successfully display the data to PDF,DOC,XLS and XLSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `ConvertToWord` need to be also in the **classpath** of your **web application**, hence its not enough to add the jar to iReport, you need to added it to WEB-INF.

As a note: Can't see the whole of your `ConvertToWord` class but if you are not overriding the  methods of `JRDefaultScriptlet` (scriplet are made to do code on `beforeDetailEval()`).

> Scriptlets are sequences of Java code that are executed every time a report event occurs. Values of report variables can be affected through scriptlets

there is no need to extend it you can simple do a class with a method and call this from your jrxml

```
public class ReportHelper{
  public static synchronized String readNumber(double xDouble) {
    ...
  }
}
```

and then call you class in jrxml es.

```
ReportHelper.readNumber($V{Sub Total} +$V{Output VAT and CST and Service Tax})
```

If you are using package, included full path of package definition. If you do not like it static, pass the ReportHelper class as a parameter or define it as a variable.

Naturally the class need's to always be in classpath.